# Why does an array get extension methods from generic IEnumerable through a back door?

Tags: c#

Each C# array is supposed to implicilty derive from class Array which implements
the non-generic `IEnumerable`

```
 public abstract class Array : ICloneable, IList, ICollection, IEnumerable, IStructuralComparable, IStructuralEquatable
```

`IEnumerable` gets only four extension methods. However, each array gets also extension methods
from the generic `IEnumerable<<T>>`. The problem is that class Array does not implement `IEnumerable<<T>>`
The MSDN docs for class Array state that "Starting with the .NET Framework 2.0, the Array class 
implements the generic interfaces like System.Collections.Generic.`IEnumerable<<T>>` 
The implementations are provided to arrays at run time, and as a result, the generic interfaces 
do not appear in the declaration syntax for the Array class"

So my question is why the class Array does not implement `IEnumerable<<T>>` explicitly when it 
implements `IEnumerable<<T>>` implicitly anyway. What does it mean that implemenation is provided 
at runtime when the compiler compiles it at compile time, and Intellisense shows extension
methods for `IEnumerable<<T>>` added to any array variable at edit time.

Comment: As to the "how does it provide the generic version at runtime": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163297/how-do-arrays-in-c-sharp-partially-implement-ilistt

Comment: This question already provided incomplete answers from similar questions in the past. The answers in the past merely quoted the documentation which fails to provide a logical justification

Comment: @Micky6789 Arrays are special, and use code from the CLR that you couldn't write yourself in C#. Eric Lippert has a little extra info about this. He doesn't go in to detail, but explains it at a high level: "... things would have been a lot different if we'd had generics in CLR v1. Arrays are essentially a generic collection type. Because they were created in a type system that did not have generics, there has to be lots of special code in the type system to handle them." https://stackoverflow.com/a/5110960/310988