# Why do Arrays implement generic collections at run time?

Tags: c#, arrays, generics

In the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) it says:

> Single-dimensional arrays implement the
> `System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>`,
> `System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>`,
> `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>`,
> `System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<T>` and
> `System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection<T>` generic interfaces.
>
> **The implementations are provided to arrays at run time.**

Why are the provided at run-time, and not in the `Array` class definition?

Comment: Not sure what you're expecting for an answer but all of these represent (naming) and provide (interface) different functionality.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why isn't Array a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324987/why-isnt-array-a-generic-type) (via [Why does an array get extension methods from generic IEnumerable through a back door?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44656480/150605))

Comment: `Why are the provided at run-time, and not in the Array class definition?` Because to do so in the class, then it would be a generic class. Arrays were around long before generics. That's just my guess.

Comment: The "why" is fairly involved, but fortunately already discussed to death on Stack Overflow. See marked duplicates for historical context and explanation of why and how arrays work the way they do.